# VS Code and Angular CLI: opening or switching to a file restarts the build

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I asked this same question on the [VS Code repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116227) and they essentially gave me a "works on my machine" answer and dumped me here. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

From my bug report:

Nearly every time I open a file in angular project VSC triggers a rebuild somehow with the Angular CLI.

I have disabled all my extensions to see if it was caused by one and the issue repeats itself, but less frequently (every 3-5 files opened vs every single file).

This doesn't prevent me from working, but its incredibly annoying and time-consuming to have to walk on eggshells while debugging a feature.

VS Code version:

> Code 1.53.0 (8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496, 2021-02-03T20:36:38.611Z)
> OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

System Info

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CPUs | Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10850H CPU @ 2.70GHz (12 x 2712) |
| GPU Status | 2d_canvas: enabled gpu_compositing: enabled multiple_raster_threads: enabled_on oop_rasterization: enabled opengl: enabled_on protected_video_decode: enabled rasterization: enabled skia_renderer: enabled_on video_decode: enabled vulkan: disabled_off webgl: enabled webgl2: enabled |
| Load (avg) | undefined |
| Memory (System) | 31.61GB (14.19GB free) |
| Process Argv | --crash-reporter-id 98980995-34b4-4020-bfc4-6617396ed52d |
| Screen Reader | no |
| VM | 0% |

Extensions: none
A/B Experiments

```
vsliv368cf:30146710
vsreu685:30147344
python383cf:30185419
vspor879:30202332
vspor708:30202333
vspor363:30204092
vswsl492cf:30211402
vstry244cf:30250196
pythonvsdeb440:30248342
pythonvsded773:30248341
pythonvspyt600cf:30251589
```

Comment: Is it possible you have configured the AutoSave functionality? Looks like it can be configured to save on window/editor change and more: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save

Comment: Good thought but no, I dont. However, I found a few comments on similar threads and added `--poll 1000` to my `ng serve`. It seems to have worked but I think its just masking an underlying problem.